Cannot log into Wordpress admin dashboard after new installation on AWS ec2
I downloaded and installed the wordpress files on my AWS ec2 instance. I also successfully created the database and db user.  I can also access the database with the user and password via phpmyadmin.
Going to the url, the first thing I notice is the installation utility is all left justified and not displaying like shown in the installation documentation.  It's like the CSS didn't get loaded.  I followed the steps anyway and got the successful installation message with the link to login.  The login page is also all left justified with no layout.  When I enter the username and password I just created, I get a pop up telling me it will be transmitted unsecured.  I click OK and the page reloads with the username and password blank again.
I've seen many instances of this while searching the problem on Google but none have reached a conclusion.  The most prevalent solution mentions changing the settings in the database wp_options for the home and site from http to https.  When I do this and go back to try to access the login page, I now get an error that the page couldn't be redirected.  I've with and without the .htaccess file with no difference.  There is a valid SSL for the domain on the ec2 instance.  I've not been able to find any answer to the unable to redirect error since it is so vague.

The answer is probably to deliberately access the site over HTTPS, yes, as Usama's answer is alluding to. I'm not sure why exactly it would work as you've described though, you'd think that that would still log you in anyway if you're accepting all the warnings. But the answer could be specifics of how you've set this all up that you haven't told us.

You say you have a valid SSL certificate: is that all set up? Are you using it? Are you going to your site over HTTPS?

It seems like the issues with CSS not loading and being unable to log into the WordPress admin dashboard might be caused by incorrect configurations related to SSL or URL settings. First, open your wp-config.php file and add the lines to define your site's URL as https, like this:

define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
(replace yourdomain.com with your actual domain).

Next, make sure your .htaccess file contains the standard WordPress rules to handle URL rewriting. If you’re using SSL, you can also add a rule to force HTTPS, ensuring that all traffic is secured.
Additionally, confirm that in your WordPress database's wp_options table, the home and siteurl values are both set to https. Finally, after making these changes, clear your browser cache and try logging in again. These steps should help resolve the layout and login issues you're encountering.
